# Play sound with reverb effect with NAudio library?

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

I am using in my C# winForms application great audio library - NAudio. I am playing sounds by the use of WAVE cache and PlayEngine and i have a question:

Is it possible (and if YES: how?) to play sound with reverb effect with NAudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAudio does not include a reverb effect. It does provide access to the raw audio samples, so you can implement your own effect algorithms. Another option might be to see if there is a Reverb MFT installed and pass the audio through (in the same way that the NAudio MFResampler works).

So the short answer is, unfortunately it's not easy to do.

Comment: Thank you Mark.
I think it is very not easy for me to do now. 
I will just batch my .wav files with reverb effect, put it into solution resources and i will make a button "Reverb" and IF statment to play reverb files.